# Is there a CSS function for slideshow image order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an image slideshow using mainly CSS and some HTML. It works but the images are coming in a random order, I want to have the images in a set order.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.slideshow {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/** SLIDESHOW **/
.slideshow,
.slideshow:after { 
    top: -9px; /*Not sure why I needed this fix*/
        position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    width: 580px;
    height: 400px;
    left: -43px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.slideshow li span { 
        position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/1-OrangeBoy.jpg"); 
    animation-delay: 1s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/2-HoldingXrays.jpg");
    animation-delay: 7s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/3-CubaEmptyShelves.jpg");
    animation-delay: 14s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/4-Cuba-PoolBehind.jpg");   
    animation-delay: 21s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/5-DahliaGirlStandingPose.jpg");
    animation-delay: 28s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/6-Elephants.jpg");
    animation-delay: 35s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(7) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/7-MagdelanaKidsWpup.jpg");
    animation-delay: 42s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(8) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/8-BullHead.jpg");
    animation-delay: 49s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(9) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/9-ChowSueKongPose.jpg");
    animation-delay: 56s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(10) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/10-DonkeyPose.jpg");
    animation-delay: 63s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(11) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/11-BorderPatrol.jpg");
    animation-delay: 70s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(12) span { 
    background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/12-Roraima.jpg");
    animation-delay: 77s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
    <li><span>5</span></li>
    <li><span>6</span></li>
    <li><span>7</span></li>
    <li><span>8</span></li>
    <li><span>9</span></li>
    <li><span>10</span></li>    
    <li><span>11</span></li>
    <li><span>12</span></li>
</ul>
```

I have attempted to use various CSS and HTML methods to try and fix this to no avail. There must be a way that we can set the order of the images properly.

Is it possible using CSS or JS to have the images go in a set order? As you see in the image links in the CSS code.

Comment: You can do this with Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

All of your spans have the same `z-index`. Just remove that and this should resolve itself. The images **are** in order but the *layers* are probably not.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.slideshow {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/** SLIDESHOW **/

.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
  top: -9px;
  /*Not sure why I needed this fix*/
  position: relative;
  width: 580px;
  width: 580px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -43px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slideshow li span {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  /* z-index: 0;*/
  animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/1-OrangeBoy.jpg");
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/2-HoldingXrays.jpg");
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/3-CubaEmptyShelves.jpg");
  animation-delay: 14s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/4-Cuba-PoolBehind.jpg");
  animation-delay: 21s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/5-DahliaGirlStandingPose.jpg");
  animation-delay: 28s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/6-Elephants.jpg");
  animation-delay: 35s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(7) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/7-MagdelanaKidsWpup.jpg");
  animation-delay: 42s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(8) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/8-BullHead.jpg");
  animation-delay: 49s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(9) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/9-ChowSueKongPose.jpg");
  animation-delay: 56s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(10) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/10-DonkeyPose.jpg");
  animation-delay: 63s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(11) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/11-BorderPatrol.jpg");
  animation-delay: 70s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(12) span {
  background-image: url("http://allencraigphotography.com/img/12-Roraima.jpg");
  animation-delay: 77s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>9</span></li>
  <li><span>10</span></li>
  <li><span>11</span></li>
  <li><span>12</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I completely agree, that's the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what's been happening is the order is correct but the loop is not

After the final image (#12), the video then starts to transition to image #4 (not #1 as it should), but immediately goes into image #5.

You can see the result as it is now in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10tYpLXjGWh0wXI_sIGU-oCdJawfU6-pk/view?usp=sharing